# Passing a Nullable parameter in cloud endpoint library

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm working with `Google Cloud Endpoint` for Java. And I create some endpoints.
Here is one of them.

```
public User registerUser(@Named("lat") double lat, @Named("lng") double lng, @Nullable @Named("contactList") List<Long> contactList, User user){
```

As you can see `contactList` is annotated as `@Nullable` sometimes I need this parameter or sometimes not. Everything is working fine when I test it on **API Explorer**

After all this, I generated client library for Android. And I'm using it like this.

```
MyApi.Builder builder = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), null);
    MyApi service = builder.build();

 service.account().registerUser(31.024937, 73.847913, user);
```

`registerUser` only provides three arguments. If I want to pass `contactList` how can I do that? There is no option to pass it in `registerUser`. If I try to pass it an error came up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found to answer my self. After looking some code of generated library I found something that all `@Nullable` parameters can't be passed into the function but set with this function check the code below for better understanding.

```
 service.account().registerUser(31.024937, 73.847913, user)
 .setContactList(contactList).execute();
```

Generated Library automatically create a function for setting `@Nullable` parameters like as `setContactList()`.